# Adult cat has chronic diarrhea (suspected IBD), no other outward issues. Concern level?

Tags: cats, health

**TL;DR**:

- 8 year old male fixed domestic shorthair cat has had diarrhea on a constant basis for at least 3 months
- No weight loss or other signs of illness
- Urinalysis/fecal flotation looked good, "slight elevation" of eosiniphils and PSL on blood test
- So far has been treated with metronidazole (7 days), switch to limited ingredient diet, Fortiflora, and in the past week has received B12 injection and new prescription hydrolyzed protein food
- No big changes in symptoms since first seeing vet

**Full details**

Cat is ~8 years old, domestic shorthair, neutered. He's big --- about 17 pounds, but vets consistently state he is not overweight, he's just really tall and long. He was around 12 pounds when we took him in as a very thin stray and a vet estimated he was just under 1 year old then. At any rate, just want to indicate that I doubt there's a weight problem. He is fully indoors since that time about 7 years ago and lives with another neutered male domestic shorthair who is also approximately 8 years old. At the time symptoms began, he was eating a couple different commercial grain-free wet foods with chicken, beef, and turkey as main ingredients. Located in the southern USA, if it matters.

Since around late May 2022, i.e. for about 3 months at the time of posting, his solid waste has been nearly 100% diarrhea. I can't say with total certainty when it started since it wouldn't have totally alarmed me to see loose stool in the litter box now and then, so I just don't know exactly how steady of a progression from normal to 100% it was. What tipped me off initially was the loud flatulence that went along with these bowel movements and on a couple occasions the fact he failed to keep it off of his leg which resulted in big messes at you might imagine.

I had noticed a couple flatulent bowel movements just before traveling and needing to board him for 7 days. Since his return from boarding the diarrhea has been the only type of bowel movement we've directly observed. There are a couple cases where there was circumstantial evidence that he may have had a solid bowel movement, but it may have been the other cat. Upon the return from boarding, our other cat was also having diarrhea but not 100% of the time. After a few weeks, we visited our vet.

Vet did a physical exam, urinalysis, fecal flotation, and blood panel. Physical exam, urinalysis, and fecal flotation showed nothing abnormal. Blood panel was mostly normal, but vet said there was slightly elevated eosiniphils and slightly elevated PSL (pancreatic enzyme). Vet stated this is consistent with although not diagnostic of IBD. Vet advised switching to a single protein and more limited ingredient diet and giving Fortiflora. We additionally did a week-long course of treatment with metronidazole on both cats. We switched to [Hound & Gatos Turkey formula](https://houndgatos.com/products/turkey-liver-2/) due to its limited ingredients and nutrition profile. The main cat in question spent one day apparently ill (lethargy, no appetite) during the metronidazole treatment which we attribute to the drug. No ultrasound yet although the vet used ultrasound for the urinalysis and said she took a "quick look" at the intestines at that time and saw no thickening.

Otherwise, there is no weight loss --- his weight has ranged from 16.5 to 17 pounds for years now and was 17 a week ago at the vet --- and he has his normal appetite (eager for food but not concerningly so) and still demands play, likes to do some wrestling and chasing with his fellow cat, etc.

The flatulence has mostly stopped but his outputs are still almost totally liquid, sometimes more like a pudding consistency but nothing like normal. Sometimes it looks rather mucous-y, if that makes sense. Initially these bowel movements smelled very bad --- there was nowhere in my house you could be and not know that somebody just used the box --- but after the food switch the scent is much less intense for both of my cats. He usually goes once a day, sometimes twice. The other cat began having normal bowel movements as soon as we switched foods. It's hard to be sure, but it seems like the food change brought about some more energy in the cat with diarrhea.

Upon returning to the vet we were prescribed a hydrolyzed protein diet which he's been fed for the past 5 days with no immediate result. He is also getting B12 injections, with the first a week ago and another coming today. We also felt a lump on his back which the vet says is a lipoma after doing a cytoscopy (phew). We will see the vet again soon.

**What do you think?**

I do research for a living so I know most of the potential issues in play but I don't have any expert judgment. Most cats I hear about with IBD-like issues online are suffering weight loss and/or other important signs of illness.

How urgent does this seem? Should we consider some more expensive diagnostics (ultrasound, biopsy)? A cat shouldn't have this much diarrhea so I want to fix it. At the same time, he seems to be feeling fine so I don't know how much I should give the diet changes etc. time to work out. I know steroid treatment could be on the horizon but I'm somewhat worried about inducing diabetes; I don't know enough about the risks or the likelihood that it would be a long-term treatment rather than a short-term one. In general I don't have a good grasp of whether we're in a "caught it early, need to treat quickly before it progresses" or "watch and wait" type of situation.

Comment: There's a risk of dehydration with diarrhea, so it's definitely worthwhile to be concerned. Did you do a slow or fast transition to the hydrolized diet? And to clarify that as well, is that a kibble or canned food? Last clarification, what's the timeline from noting the problem, to moving to the LID, to the latest switch to hydrolized? Otherwise, this is a great question!

Comment: Have you considered a fecal PCR test?  There are a few diseases that cause chronic diarrhea but won’t show up on a standard fecal test.